# “Error opening column file” in MariaDB Columnstore data cpimport

Tags: mariadb

I'm trying to import a large file, around 2GB, into `MariaDB Columnstore`. Other files that are smaller worked fine, so I suspect it's a size issue. I create the table with engine `Columnstore` with no problem. Then I run the command:

```
sudo cpimport -s '|' -E '"' industry  fdic_callr_rcr_regulat_capital fdic_callr_rcr_regulat_capital.csv
```

And I get:

```
Using table OID 20208 as the default JOB ID
Input file(s) will be read from : /home/sofuser/data/callr
Job description file : /var/lib/columnstore/data/bulk/tmpjob/20208_D20210617_T180941_S792633_Job_20208.xml
Log file for this job: /var/lib/columnstore/data/bulk/log/Job_20208.log
2021-06-17 18:09:42 (2870) INFO : successfully loaded job file /var/lib/columnstore/data/bulk/tmpjob/20208_D20210617_T180941_S792633_Job_20208.xml
2021-06-17 18:09:42 (2870) INFO : Job file loaded, run time for this step : 0.40599 seconds
2021-06-17 18:09:42 (2870) INFO : PreProcessing check starts
2021-06-17 18:09:42 (2870) INFO : input data file /home/sofuser/data/callr/fdic_callr_rcr_regulat_capital.csv
2021-06-17 18:09:50 (2870) ERR  : Error opening column file for OID-21217; DBRoot-1; partition-0; segment-0; filename-/var/lib/columnstore/data1/000.dir/000.dir/082.dir/225.dir/000.dir/FILE000.cdf;  opening a column file. The file was not found or was inaccessible. [1052]
2021-06-17 18:09:50 (2870) CRIT : Error in pre-processing the job file for table industry.fdic_callr_rcr_regulat_capital [1052]
2021-06-17 18:09:50 (2870) ERR  : Error deleting meta file; Error deleting bulk rollback data subdirectory /var/lib/columnstore/data1/bulkRollback/20208_data; [1053]
```

NOTE: the file that's not found is not the input file, it's a file that MariaDB has in its database structure.

[This is the log](http://www.sofiana.com/temp/Job_20208.log)

Comment: Well... Are you sure, that you have enough free disk space available under `/var`? I believe, that you need approximately more than two times of the files size for the import to work.

Comment: Yes I am positive

Answer (score 0):

maybe the file was deleted or removed or something to do with the update or a bug wich is super rare